# Added field to Basic Page Content Type is not displayed in the page

Tags: 7, nodes, rating

This question may be a bit silly but I have been struggling with it for a long time and still no solution:

I have added the Star Rating Module to display rating stars in my pages. I have enabled the module and configured the "Basic Page" Content type to have the "rating" field. The point is that I edit a page, assign a rating properly but... when I view the generated page the starts don't show up!

I have tried adding another field, this time a text field, but it doesn't appear on the page either.

Any idea why additional fields added to "Basic Page" aren't displayed in the page?

Comment: It happens to all users. I have created a new content type and every field I add is displayed when reviewing the pages generated with it. However it doesn't work for "Basic page" ????

Comment: That was it! Thanks Gisle, I hadn't seen that option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about putting fields on the Basic Page.

However, to be visible, you have to make sure that the field is not `<Hidden>`.

To check that, go to the *Manage Display*  panel for the bundle (content type) you've got problems with.